# Use of Static variable

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access and set this variable `$lang`, but its value is not updating:

```
class LocalizationController {
    static public $lang='ar';

    static public function setHoorayLocale($var)
    {
        $lang=$var;
        return $lang;
    }

}
```

I am setting value of `$lang` in this way:

```
LocalizationController::$lang = 'en'
```

but the value of `$lang` in `LocalizationController` is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class you can assign the a value to the static variable with

```
self::$lang = "de";
```

or

```
LocalizationController::$lang = 'en'
```

as well.

also you need to return this value:

```
return self::$lang;
```

or

```
return LocalizationController::$lang;
```

Comment: I did, but it's not updating with this method

Comment: LocalizationController::$lang = 'en'

Comment: class LocalizationController {
        static public $lang='ar';
        static public function setHoorayLocale($var)
        {
            self::$lang=$var;
            return $lang;
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class LocalizationController {
    static public $lang='ar';
    static public function setHoorayLocale($var)
    {
        return self::$lang = $var;
    }
}

$obj = new LocalizationController;
$value = $obj->setHoorayLocale('en');
echo $value;// output en
```